# Is there a name for a type of letter where the writer asks an institution to provide a service?

Tags: word-request, legalese, writing, formal-language

In my country, it happens quite often that a citizen needs a service from a government agency, but there's no exact form for the service that the citizen wants. In such case, in Serbia, we'd write a letter type which we call молба. The direct translation would be "request". It usually looks something like this:

> I kindly request that the  Agency for Y issues me а certificate of YY.
>   I need the YY certificate due to J, K and L reasons. Attached are the
>   proofs of my YY-ness. Best regards, Andreja

I've been trying to find a name for such a letter type in English, but I can't seem to figure out how it could be called.

Comment: The term in your native tongue is very generic if it can be translated as "request", but your question assumes it is a specific term, and so your question is not making much sense to me.

Comment: @TRomano Well, the issue is that I'm not aware of any better term in English that I might use. It is a very specific term. Perhaps a better translation would be "kind request"? It implies that the letter writer is not in a higher position than the letter recipient, however the writer is also not in a desperate situation.

Comment: Your sample letter is also very generic. Is it a "certificate request"? What kind of certificate? Birth certificate?  Certificate of occupancy? Death certificate?

Comment: I'd call it an application.

Comment: @TRomano Actually, we use the same terminology for any type of certificate, so it's not clear to me what the difference would be. The "template" I posted is from a letter I used to get the "Harmonized Amateur Radio Examination Certificate", if it matters, but I'm looking for a name which is not specific to the type of document requested, if that's possible. The important point is that I either need a document or a specific service.

Comment: @Lucian Sava I'm looking at the "application" description at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/application) and it might fit the number 5 there, but again, I'm not sure if application or appeal would be better.

Comment: We don't have a term for this. Based on your comments, this sounds like something that relates specifically to some form of personal hierarchy... that just doesn't exist in most of the English-speaking world. Generally, if you need a form, you submit a request... that's it. There's no special word. So, if I needed another copy of my diploma, I'd write a letter (or more likely fill out a form) and mail it to them requesting a copy of the document and include the necessary identifying documenation. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, as a native citizen of the USA, there is no term for this.

Generally, if we need something from a government agency, there's a form we fill out and submit (likely with some required documentation). That's it. We don't necessarily need to write a letter to go along with it and, if we do, that letter doesn't have a specific name.

For example, when I recently needed a copy of my son's birth certificate, I found the [form on the city's website](https://austintexas.gov/department/obtaining-birth-or-death-certificate), filled it out, and then had my husband turn it in at their office in person. I could have submitted it digitally or by mail but that would have taken longer (and cost more). If I'd mailed it, I wouldn't have enclosed a letter. The website linked above details the necessary enclosures:

> - Effective immediately, all mail-in requests require notarized proof of identification.
> - A completed application (download and print one in English or Spanish)
> - A check or money order payable to the Office of Vital Records ($23 for each copy of a birth certificate; $21 for each death certificate plus $4 for each additional copy)
> - A copy of your current government-issued photo identification
>     A copy of proof of residence, such as utility bill, voter registration, etc., if different than the address on your photo ID
> - A copy of a current government-issued identification of the person who signs the check (if different from the requestor)
> - A stamped self-addressed envelope (use an express mail envelope for express mail delivery).

None of the things listed above include any sort of letter, though the entire submission is referred to as a "request".

So, if you're filling out a form, that's called an "application" and if there's not a form, you're just sending a "request". There's no specific word.